# Use getJSON for Data in Ember.js

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js

First time using Ember.

I've read everything I can and can use help building my understanding.

I've been able to render the Ember template inside the rails template.

Now I'm working on binding data using getJSON to the ember template, but I'm getting a few errors. `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'reopenClass' of undefined` `Error while loading route: TypeError {}`

**api/v1/newslinks_controller.rb**

```
class Api::V1::NewslinksController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with Newslink.all
  end

  def create
    respond_with Newslink.create(params[:newslink])
  end

  def update
    respond_with Newslink.update(params[:id], params[:newslink])
  end

  def destroy
    respond_with Newslink.destroy(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**/api/v1/newslinks.json**

```
{"newslinks":[{"id":1,"title":"A Sample Post","navlink":"This will be a simple post record."}]}
```

**app.js**

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({
      LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
      LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true,
      LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
      rootElement: '#ember',
      ready: function() {
        console.log('I am app');
      }
    });

    App.Router.map(function() {
        this.resource('newslinks', { path: '/' });
        console.log("I am router")
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    });

    App.NewslinksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
        return App.Newslink.all();
      }
    });

    App.Newslink.reopenClass({
         all: function() {
           return $.getJSON("/api/v1.newslinks_controller.json").then(function(response) {
                      var newslinks = [];

                      response.newslinks.forEach(function(newslink) {
                  newslinks.push(App.Newslink.create(newslink));
                }); 
                      return newslinks;
              });
         }
    });
```

**newslinks.handlebars**

```
<div class="offset1">
  <h1>Newslinks</h1>

  <ul>
    {{#each newslink in model}}
      <li>{{newslink.title}}</li>
      <li>{{newslink.navlink}}</li>
    {{else}}
      <li>There is no news.</li>
    {{/each}}
  </ul>

  {{outlet}}
</div>
```

Grateful for any assistance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't declared your `App.Newslink` class.

Use:

```
App.Newslink = Ember.Object.extend();
```

before

```
App.Newslink.reopenClass ...
```

Comment: Ok, great. Thanks. The only remaining thing is to feed the right url in there, I think. If you know what that should look like, let me know. Right now, I'm getting a `GET http://localhost:3000/api/v1/newslinks_controller.json 404 (Not Found)` error